# Sum of Custom Meta written by Authour

Tags: php, sql

I have a custom meta call post_views_count that collects the views of all posts...

I want to create a query that pulls in all posts by a certain author, gathers the custom meta for post views and then add them all together.

End result - Total view count for all authors posts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution

```
 

$authorPost = get_posts(array('author' => 1));foreach ($catPost as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
}
$idList = implode(",", $ids); //turn the array into a comma delimited list

$meta_key = 'post_view';
$allview = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
                                  SELECT sum(meta_value) 
                                  FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                                  WHERE meta_key = %s 
                                  AND post_id in (" . $idList . ")", $meta_key));
echo 'user 1 All posts View Count'.$allview .'';
```

Comment: Cheers that worked perfectly :)